# Allow paragraph separation in bounty message

Tags: feature-request, bounty

When writing a custom message for a bounty you are allowed a generous 3000 characters. But you are only allowed one paragraph. That makes the message hard to read when two or three paragraphs would be appropriate.

While writing the message, one has the illusion that multiple paragraphs are possible. However, after posting the bounty, the message is all mashed together into a single paragraph.

[image]

**Feature request:**

- Don't filter out the new line characters.

Comment: New hobby once this is [status-completed]: posting bounties on high-profile questions, with messages containing 3k newlines ;) This might just be the result of multiple-whitespace-stripping measures which are present in multiple parts of SO.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Prevent newline characters from being repeated and/or have a limit to the total number of newline characters.

Comment: In others @Words use the markdown render on the bounty messages.

Comment: Why the heck do you need **3000 characters** to explain a bounty? If you have that much content, I think you just need a *new question*, or to edit it if it's already your own.

Comment: @jpmc26, I don't know. I've never needed that many. But I have needed two paragraphs, which is what this feature request is about.

Comment: Why do you need two paragraphs? Even that seems excessive to me. A real life example in your question might go a long way.

Comment: @jpmc26, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419766/3681880), for example. I wanted to explain the problem with the old answers in the first paragraph and what I was hoping to achieve from the bounty in the second paragraph. It works as a single paragraph, but it would be more readable as two.

Comment: @jpmc26 you're missing the common and obvious use case of [illustrations](http://imgur.com/dXwi4)

Comment: Because introducing whitespace makes blocks of text more readable. Why would you *not* need paragraphs? @jpmc26

Comment: @CodyGray Because a long bounty description is not a good thing.

Comment: Whatever someone wants to achieve with a long bounty description would probably better require an edit on the question itself. So 3000 characters is too much and should be lowered.

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Line breaks/paragraphs for bounty text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124016)

Comment: @Suragch your bounty would have been better a new question on Code Review instead.

Comment: Are there any examples of when enough words to warrant paragraph separation were actually warranted for a bounty?

Comment: Just tried to replicate with 5 questions, spending 2500 points. Can I make the bounties undone somehow?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, Yes, you are probably right. But it isn't a wrong use of a bounty on Stack Overflow, is it?

Comment: @Suragch I am not realy sure, but your bounty implies you want to have feedback on your answer (not that the question should be answered). This means, someone need a space for replying to your bounty. On Code Review it would be an answer, in this situation only a comment? Maybe someone with more experience could bring some better detailed answer, my feeling is just, it would be more apropriate on Code Review.

Comment: One way or the other, it should probably change.  I think that everyone can agree that a single 3000 character paragraph is worse than either a shorter limit or the same amount of text broken out to be actually readable.  Really, independent of the specific reasoning of bounty length, there shouldn't be any area where the site allows for that amount of text and forces it into a single paragraph.

Answer (score -2):

#### The OP's case

The OP linked [this specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419766/1394393) in comments. The bounty reason entered is:

> The old answers, while helpful, did not fully answer how a View should receive input from a Keyboard. The accepted answer ended up subclassing TextView rather than View, and @Carl's answer required disabling keyboard functionality with `InputType.TYPE_NULL` and putting the `BaseInputConnection` into "dummy mode". I added a new answer that I believe is more versatile and follows the current documentation guidelines. **However, because I will be using this in a library, I need more eyes on it to tell me if I am missing anything.** Please leave a comment if there are adjustments I should make. Or if I am on the wrong track altogether, please add a new answer.

(emphasis mine)

This seems like an incorrect use of bounties to me. The bounty in this case is being used as an attempt to garner review of an existing answer. This seems wrong for multiple reasons.

1. We have a dedicated [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site for this.
2. Bounties are designed to attract *new answers* or *award* existing answers, not attract improvements on an answer posted by the person offering the bounty. (This doesn't preclude a new answer building off an old one with significant improvements, but that doesn't seem to be what the OP of this question is seeking.) Indeed, if the OP attracts the attention they want, it could result in downvoting of their answer if it has major problems and eventual self deletion.
3. This bounty wasn't created to reward an answer. It was made for the purpose of attracting attention to *their own* answer. It's not clear what kind of answer this bounty would even be awarded to. Bounties provide an incentive to answer by giving an extra reward. (Yes, sometimes that reward is for an excellent existing answer instead of a new one. That doesn't change their purpose or how they're supposed to function.)

In short, I think the OP of this question would be better served by posting on Code Review and posting an answer on this question later.

#### General Case

I think the OP's example points to why this feature shouldn't be implemented: the majority of cases where a paragraph break is going to be needed indicates that the bounty offerer (Is there a word for this?) is probably attempting to do something overly complicated, and in such cases, a bounty probably isn't the best way to go.

I can think of two cases when a bounty is being used somewhat more in line with the intended usage but that a long explanation would be required:

1. None of the answers work for the bounty offerer's *specific* use case. In this case, SO's advice is to **post a new question** that details why the solutions in the old question don't work for them. If it doesn't attract an answer, they can add a bounty to *their* question a couple days later.
2. The bounty offerer already owns the question, but because of details they left out, the existing answers don't work for their use case. A new question would still be appropriate in this case if the details make it significantly different, but if they don't change much, the OP could just edit in details and *then* off the bounty. There's no reason to put such details in the bounty message.

The bottom line: If you need to add details to the question, they belong in a question body somewhere, not the bounty reason. If that's not what you're doing and the existing reasons don't suffice, you're probably not using bounties the way they should be.

#### What should we do?

Instead of adding paragraph breaks, the bounty reason length should be *shortened* to discourage long messages. This will discourage misuse of bounties and encourage existing site policy (new questions, question edits, doing things on the appropriate SE, etc.).

Comment: I disagree with this because the point of bounties is to draw attention. There is a free form option for a reason. There is also a proscribed option that is something along the lines of "To reward an exceptional answer that already exists". I do not believe that this is a misuse of the bounty system at all.

Comment: @TinyGiant What are your thoughts on my 3rd point? That there's no criteria for who this person will award the bounty to? In this particular case, it seems the bounty offered is trying to attract comments, rather than answers. Also, if you know of any, I'd like to see any blogs or posts where the SO team explained why they allowed such a large free form field. I agree it's curious, but I don't know why they did it.

Comment: Ultimately any answer should answer _the_ question, any "instructions" in the bounty message are second to that.

Comment: @TinyGiant Except this bounty wasn't even trying to attract answers. Bounties are supposed to attract answers by *rewarding* them. (Yes, sometimes a bounty is used to reward an answer after it was posted. It's still rewarding an answer.) This bounty isn't designed to do that. How does it motivate anyone to contribute an answer? Heck, why is another answer even needed on this question? The person who added the bounty was trying to attract attention to *their own* answer, not attract more answers.

Comment: Well then it was an innefficient use. No one has to answer the question. Everyone is free to not answer the question as much as they like. If no one answers the question, the only person the bountier will affect in any way is themselves.

Comment: @TinyGiant Not true. Other users look for bounty questions to answer sometimes. If they don't answer, it wastes their time. If they do answer just to game the bounty, they're probably contributing a low quality post. I've edited the answer a bit to clarify some points from my previous comment. Thanks for helping me flush it out.

Comment: If you're viewing the bounty list and you find a question you don't know the answer to, is your time wasted?

Comment: @TinyGiant If I'm viewing the bounty list and think I know the answer to a question only to find the bounty is just there to promote someone else's answer, is my time wasted?

Comment: @jpmc26: No, you aren't. Because you still have the ability to post an answer yourself, and the bounty offerer can choose to reward your answer instead if they so desire.

Comment: @NicolBolas So I can write an answer based on the slim chance that the offerer will actually do something with the bounty, while I ignore the description? The fact that the bounty description doesn't request any new answers also strongly suggests there isn't much information to add. So what would I put in a new answer?