# Should I flag a question because of an extensive bounty notice that is prompting for updated answers?

Tags: support

This question [How do you get the rails generated id of a form element for reference in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4819696/2427065) have an open bounty of 50.

But the person who placed the bounty added lots of information in the notice and the reason for bounty is existing answers are outdated.

In this case, when the period is over and notice removed, future visitors may not know what is the difference between existing answer and new answer.

I think it should be made as an edit to the question or posted as a new question and the notice should be small.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? The question isn't tagged for any specific version of the technologies involved. If there's a better way since 2011 why would it be bad for the answers to include it?

Comment: I'd say the bounty description introducing a completely new question *is* sort of a problem. That's not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that is the reason I asked here. It should be either an update or a new question I think

Comment: Ah OK I'm not familiar with rails. If the issue in the bounty notice is not fundamentally the same as the one in the Q and it wouldn't be possible to come up with answers applicable to both then that is a problem.

Comment: Why don't you ask the user why they offered the bounty this way. They have a chat account.

Comment: @rene  He can't cancel the bounty anyway. I can ask him but it may prevent him from doing so in future only

Comment: [Repost of my comment from another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350369/allow-paragraph-separation-in-bounty-message#comment480256_350369): _Whatever someone wants to achieve with a long bounty description would probably better require an edit on the question itself. So 3000 characters is too much and should be lowered._

Comment: Oh look....a chameleon!

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understood what you're saying @Ihazkode

Comment: @SagarV -  a [chameleon](http://7wallpapers.net/wp-content/uploads/11_Chameleon.jpg) as in a question that morphs into another question.

Comment: You're making assumptions about the bounty notice purpose without understanding neither the original question nor the bounty notice. If it was a chameleon I would agree that the bounty should be canceled. But if it was a chameleon it is a nonsense: why should I invest 50 rep points to request an updated answer to a question that has only got 22 upvotes, instead of asking a new question, and add a bounty later on if needed? The reason I don't ask a new question is because I'm indeed asking the same question. Another question with the example in the bounty would have been given the same title.

Comment: @ClaudioFloreani what's a chameleon?

Comment: @Pochi that has already been answered just a few comments above.

Answer (score 16):

I pointed out that both examples are **two special cases** of the question. The author gives just **one** example of *“Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element”* and I'm giving **another** example. Example A and Example B. But the question is:

> “How do you get the Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element for
>   reference in JavaScript?”

It's not *“Please fix this code because I don't know how to refer to the Ruby on Rails generated id in this javascript code”*.
The original question is general purpose, and it's still lacking a decent answer. Furthermore currently accepted answer (“creating a custom form builder”) is considered bad practice nowadays.

The answer may just reply to the question title, or even better give a working example for both case A and case B. If the answer has some unclear reference to the bounty's additional example, I will edit the answer to make it self-comprehensive.

---

[UPDATE - I EDITED THE ORIGINAL QUESTION]

As some people have suggested, I edited the original question to make it more clear that is a general purpose question, and it is not stricly related to the specific piece of code the original author placed in, as it is only one example and I gived another example.

[Here is the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16590691)

The reviewer @koby-douek has rejected it with the following motivation:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

So what's going on here? It's clear that I am not addressing the author of the post.

In my (humble) opinion too many users have privileges to review the community without the necessary understanding of what they are reviewing. This is really stucking StackOverflow (and excuse the pun).

If I had been placed the question as a separate question I'm pretty sure it will have been flagged as a duplicated. If I place the motivation of the bounty in the bounty notice, it should have been make an edit. If I make an edit, someone refuses it completely misunderstanding the sense of the edit.

---

[VERY LONG OT – YES I SHOULD HAVE PLACED IT AS A SEPARATE QUESTION]

Too many people are so greed with their reputation, that their goal is the reputation itself and not the benefit of the community. And the saddest notice is that the most greedy people have gained the greatest power.

I personally have quite lost hope this community that once was so collaborating, useful and promising. I see more “*you are using this site the wrong way, let me show you how you are supposed to use it*” than real answers. The only people that do really answer questions nowadays are newcomers.

**Providing a good answer needs effort to understand and to discuss with the author. Reviewing here seems to need neither the understanding nor the discussion.**

No wonder everyone here is get more involved on reviewing the community and gaining privileges than in helping people understanding the technologies. And the proof is that reviewers too often don't even understand what they are reviewing. Someone states that you don't have to understand the topic to review it, that's true if you get involved with the parties, asking why and wherefore, before taking a decision. That how a good moderator (in its broadest meaning) should act.

“*I don't even know what you are talking about but please shut up because that's not the way you are supposed to talk about it*” is not taking this community anywhere. Too many “*I know how StackOverflow should be*” have lost of sight the main goal, that is not to teach how to make a question or an answer, but to help people learn with the help of the community. I'm not encouraging the “please fix my code” practice at all, but if someone is willing to help even those questions, than let they do it. And duplicated question don't have to be closed at the first vague resemblance of another one — that so easy now that the vague resemblance are suggested to anyone willing to flag it — because if a question or an answer is not useful it won't get enough attention.

Less flags, and more answers. Less reviewing, and more competence. In my (humble) opinion, this is what StackOverflow desperately needs to stop sinking. That's why people are moving to more liberal networks as Reddit, or to networks with more competent answers as Quora.

Now, feel free to flag this answer as “OT” and ask to place it as a separate meta-question.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in.  Know that we're not attacking or accusing you personally, but there are concerns around how you're using a feature of the site, which seems...contentious to say the least.  Strangely, it also seems like there's no prior stance for this specific use case of bounties.  In spite of that, my stance is, sans context and sans understanding Ruby, how am I meant to interpret the message of your bounty?  It's not adding guidance, nor rationale explaining what you're looking for; it *looks* like it's asking *another* question.

Comment: Thank you Makoto for pointing out the purpose of this meta discussion. Please notice I'm not taking this personally, but I'm just drawing attention to the fact that you are discussing an issue that has nothing to do with the question in object. As @Pekka-웃 pointed out, *if the bounty description introduces a completely new question is sort of a problem*. But it's not the case, as the bounty description is just giving an updated example of the question problem. I've already edited the original question to explain better what does the question title asks for, including both examples.

Comment: I agree with @Makoto.. you say *here* "It's not 'please fix this code because I don't know how to refer to...'" but yet your bounty text gives a *specific problem* and ends with "How can I reference..?", so perhaps you can see the confusion. Sometimes authors write a generic title for a specific problem in the body, but you seem to assume the OP was simply giving an example but actually wanted a generic solution.

Comment: For your OT part, that are more reviewers which cause issues than moderators. Using moderator/moderation term can be confusing with the specific meaning it has on Stack Overflow. Reviewers are doing moderation, but have far less power than Stack Overflow moderators. Better speak about reviewing for not confusing with SO moderators. I have up-vote for the OT part, because me too, I am considering the reviewing broken. It seems to incite too many reviewers not actually understanding what they are reviewing to still vote for action instead of skipping (or filtering with tags the review queue).

Comment: @Frédéric I've edited, distinguishing “reviewers” from “moderators”. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

It is their bounty and they are free, to some extent, to explain what they expect from a new answer. I do assume the extra context is inline with the question as seem to be the case here.

It is up to any one who posts an answer to do so in the context of the question. They can decide to either

- Edit the question to incorporate the relevant part of the bounty text in the question if they see fit without invalidating existing answers, or
- use the bounty text in their own answer to highlight a different take on the issue not addressed by the OP of the question.

In case no new answers are created for the extra context offered by the benefactor the bounty will expire without being awarded. Should the question have been edited beforehand the edit wouldn't have made sense at all.

Although it is a bit unclear why the user offered that bounty in this way (maybe they had asked that question but it got closed as a duplicate of this one and they don't see fit to make their question more distinct) the call to flag (and the comments that suggest the user did wrong) to have the bounty refunded is strange. I can see how both question and answer(s) might get better. If no one takes the bounty on, nothing changed.

**tl;dr** I don't see how this is abusing or malice or hurting quality. Either we get a better question and/or answers or in 7 days the world order is restored to its former self. We or moderators don't need to do anything. Only if the bounty is asking a completely new question it is maybe best to flag for a moderator if contacting the user didn't clarify the intent.

Comment: Only mods can probably "edit bounty text".

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I meant to edit the question to include the bounty text,, not to edit the bounty notice itself. I have calrified that part of my answer. Sorry for being unclear about that and thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

My personal thoughts on this: flag away.  The rationale for that bounty seems to be trying to ask a different question to the original.  That's not how bounties work *at all*.

The only entities that can fix this are moderators.

Comment: and sadly the mod declined the flag. +1 for making me think I took the right decision

Comment: I'd love to know why they did... Here I'm thinking this is as clear cut as it gets.

Comment: The bountier has posted a comment on the question stating `I would like to point out that the additional example in the bounty is just another particular case where the answer will be useful. It's not a different question. To be acceptable the answer should be enough general purpose to fit both the original example and mine. Both examples shows a case where it's necessary to “get the Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element for reference in JavaScript`

Comment: Yes @MartinSmith after the flag declined, I asked the bountier to do so, in chat

Comment: @SagarV Well if the questioner is correct and both questions are basically asking "how do I get the Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element for reference in JavaScript" what's the problem?

Comment: @Martin: It feels like it should be a separate question which references the now-bountied question. Further, moderators should remain technology-neutral when making these kinds of decisions. There are already established patterns to address the bountier's issues with existing questions like this.

Comment: @Makoto the technology neutral nature of moderators means that one shouldn't flag surely? What logic are you expecting the moderators to apply here? It's going to require some evaluation of the contents of the bounty message and question.

Comment: @MartinSmith A moderator shouldn't need to know anything specific about the technology to recognize that the bounty text is asking a new question.